# Db2 - How to return the condition value if the condition is failed?

Tags: sql, db2

Assume there is a column in a table.

```
Name  add
xxx   yyy
yyy   zzz
```

I need to search if the Name column contains the name 'aaa' if not return aaa.

Could some one please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you add the result you're expecting for this input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uion`

```
select Name
from tab
where Name = 'aaa'
union
select 'aaa'
```

`Union` elimnates duplicates so if 1st query return `aaa` it won't be repetaed

Comment: This query selects all the `aaa` from the table, adds another `aaa`, and there removes all the duplicates - that's exactly the same as just doing `select 'aaa'`.

Comment: @Mureinik It's just example how to do the trick. I don't believe OP has this tables and this data id his DB

Comment: @Aravind `union` should work. Do you run my query directly or you changed it?

Comment: @Parado,  I jst want to view the result as 'aaa' and i dont want the other values in that column.

Comment: @Aravind so you don't need `select Name from tab ...`? :)

Comment: Yes. I need only 'aaa' if the value is not present in the column.

Comment: I mean what Mureinik said. You don't need looking for `aaa` in table, you need only display it don't have to use query `select  name...`, do you?

Comment: What i need is, i need to find if the column name contains the name 'aaa', if yes, just leave it, if not return 'aaa' as execution result.

Comment: @Aravind For me you want to to always display `aaa` :) Above query will do it.

Comment: @Parado Yep, its working. One more clarification: How to verify for multiple values.  I.e where name = aaa, bbb, ccc and return the value which is not there.

Comment: @Aravind You have to repeat `select '...'` for every value `select 'aaa' union select 'bbb' union select 'ccc' ... `

Comment: Can this be done in single statement to compare many values., as we do it in  in statement.

Comment: @Aravind I don't know another way